# Java get special characters from string

Tags: java, string, substring

Given a random String, I want to be able to extract certain characters from my string (`+`,`-`,`*`,`/`), one after each other.

Let's say the String is `wejri+234-wer*324sdf/`
How can I retrieve those 4 operators?

If I had to extract everything between those operators, I would use `String.split("\\+|\\-|\\*|\\/");`, but if I had to do it the other way around, how would I achieve that?

The amount of characters between those operators can vary heavily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex to remove all characters but `+, -, *, /`:

```
String text = "wejri+234-wer*324sdf/";
String res = text.replaceAll("[^+\\-\\*/]", "");   // - and * need to be escaped
// > res = "+-*/"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s CharMatcher:

```
System.out.println(
  CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER_OR_DIGIT
             .and(CharMatcher.ASCII)
             .removeFrom("wejri+234-wer*324sdf/"));
```

Output:

> +-*/

Or, if you want to go with regular expressions, I'd go for the `\w` character class:

```
System.out.println("wejri+234-wer*324sdf/".replaceAll("\\w+",""));
```

---

Update: `CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER_OR_DIGIT` is deprecated, and there is no canonical replacement, but you can easily roll your own:

```
private static final CharMatcher JAVA_LETTER_OR_DIGIT = 
    CharMatcher.forPredicate(Character::isJavaIdentifierPart)
               .precomputed();
```

Note that you want to store this in a constant, as precompute is a moderately expensive operation, and you don't want to do that every time.

Comment: Can you please update answer as I am getting alert that JAVA_LETTER_OR_DIGIT is deprecated.